# XML with Namespace Processing using Pig/Hive

Tags: xml, hadoop, xml-parsing, hive, apache-pig

I was trying to parse an xml with namespace and was wondering what would be the best way to go forward. i know pig and hive both provides support for XPath UDF , but does it work for xml's with namespace ? 
i tried with pig and hive with no result .when i googled came across this link and the link says it does not.
[Hive Name Space Link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201212.mbox/%3CBLU162-W4FBCDC9057D49232E7A00D0370@phx.gbl%3E)

I can use Map-Reduce with A DOM/SAX parser to do this , but was wondering if this can be done through hive or pig.

If anyone can direct me that would help me alot.

Thanks!!

Comment: You can try to write **custom UDF** and return the output which you want.